# условие на URL JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 var a = window.location.toString();
                $(function(){
                 if(a = 'https://www.ssylk.com/'){
                     $('.downbar').css('display', 'block')
                 }  else{
                      $('.downbar').css('display', 'none')
                 } 
                });
```

Есть код, который должен проверить ссылку. Если ссылка и текущее положение совпадают , то блок показывается, иначе - нет. Этот код не работает, помогите разобраться в чем проблема, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вместо оператор `=` нужен был `==`. Сам решил свою задачу.

Comment: Вообще, нужно `===`, но ладно)